# how to covert character within each column as sub-column without duplication

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I have a data.frame file like this:
input:

```
1 200 444 444
2 310 NA  444
3 310 NA  444
4 NA  444 444
5 200 444 444
6 200 NA  444
7 310 444 444 
8 310 876 444
9 310 876 444
10 NA  876 444
```

I want to convert ecah character within each column as a sub-column and I want to put either 1 or zero in rows in the way that they represent if the the sub column was observed in that specific row or not:
Output data.frame :

```
   c1.200 c1.310 c2.444 c2.876 c3.444
1   1      0      1      0      1 
2   0      1      0      0      1
3   0      1      0      0      1
4   0      0      1      0      1
5   1      0      1      0      1
6   1      0      0      0      1
7   0      1      1      0      1
8   0      1      0      1      1
9   0      1      0      1      1
10  0      0      0      1      1
```

is there any solution in R to do this? Meanwhile, my real data had 117000 rows and 10,000 columns.

Comment: What if `310` or `876` were also repeated in the same row? Will a new column be created for every repeat to keep the data frame binary?

Comment: @ Richard Scriven: when there is NA, then it must be set as zero in output.

Comment: @ Pierre Lafortune:it does not matter. as you see in row 7, 444 is repeated 2 times in out put file.

Comment: He's asking, what if a row is `310 310 444`?  Then according to your output, you would need a second `310` column.  And the same for `876`.  And then, what if all three are `444`?  Would you need three `444` columns?  This is a bit confusing so far

Comment: @ Richard Scriven: yes that is true. if a row is 310 310 444 then you would need a second row for 310 . and if are 444 you would need 3 columns for 444. is that still confusing?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense and be easier to read if you had it as `200 310 444 444 876`?

Comment: @ Richard Scriven: no because my data is in fact genotype code along a chromosome region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this using `table` from `base R`.  We `unlist` the dataset, `paste` with the new column names that start with `c`, remove the `NA` elements using `is.na`, get the `table` with the sequence of rows and the `paste` vector.

```
nm1 <- paste0('c', 1:3, '.')[col(dat)]
v1 <- unlist(dat)
i1 <- !is.na(v1)
newdat <- as.data.frame.matrix(table((1:nrow(dat))[row(dat)][i1], 
                         paste0(nm1[i1], v1[i1])))
newdat
#     c1.200 c1.310 c2.444 c2.876 c3.444
#  1       1      0      1      0      1
#  2       0      1      0      0      1
#  3       0      1      0      0      1
#  4       0      0      1      0      1
#  5       1      0      1      0      1
#  6       1      0      0      0      1
#  7       0      1      1      0      1
#  8       0      1      0      1      1
#  9       0      1      0      1      1
#  10      0      0      0      1      1
```

Comment: @ akrun:my input is a txt data frame which name is dat, I am wondering in which part of your script I should replace my dat.frame name? and how I should extract the output as a data.frame?

Comment: @zara Replaced `df1` with `dat`.  It should work now.

Comment: @zara Also, wrap with `as.data.frame.matrix(`

Comment: @ akrun thanks. but how to extract the output as a data.frame like new.txt file?

Comment: @zara You can use `write.csv` as in jeremycg's answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
newdat <- dat %>% setNames(paste0("c", 1:ncol(.), ".")) %>%
        mutate(row = row_number(), n = 1) %>%
        gather(key, val, -row, -n) %>%
        na.omit %>%
        unite(keyval, key, val, sep = "") %>%
        spread(keyval, n, fill = 0)

   row c1.200 c1.310 c2.444 c2.876 c3.444
1    1      1      0      1      0      1
2    2      0      1      0      0      1
3    3      0      1      0      0      1
4    4      0      0      1      0      1
5    5      1      0      1      0      1
6    6      1      0      0      0      1
7    7      0      1      1      0      1
8    8      0      1      0      1      1
9    9      0      1      0      1      1
10  10      0      0      0      1      1
```

I used this dataset, as `dat`:

```
structure(list(V2 = c(200L, 310L, 310L, NA, 200L, 200L, 310L, 
310L, 310L, NA), V3 = c(444L, NA, NA, 444L, 444L, NA, 444L, 876L, 
876L, 876L), V4 = c(444L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 
444L, 444L, 444L)), .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

To output, use `write.csv(newdat, file="yourfilename.csv")`

Comment: @ jeremycg: I tried to run your script but I got these error: > library(dplyr)
Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
> library(tidyr)
Error in library(tidyr) : there is no package called ‘tidyr’
could you please guide me for how to install these libraries?

Comment: `install.packages("dplyr")` then `install.packages("tidyr")`. You'll only need to do each once.

Comment: @ jeremycg:how can I extract this new data file as a data.frame format? I mean if iwant to have this output as new.txt file, then what should I add to the script?

Comment: see the edit - basically save the output as `newdat` then write it to csv using `write.csv`