# How to convert a character within each column as sub-column without duplication

Tags: shell

I have a data file. It will looks like:

input1:

```
1 20022 44444 44444
2 31012 22233 44444
3 31012 22233 00444
4 20022 44444 00444
5 20022 44444 00444
6 20022 44444 00444
7 31012 44444 00444 
8 31012 44444 00444
9 31012 87634 44444
10 20022 87634 44444
```

I want to convert each character within each column as a sub-column and I want to put either 1 or zero in rows in the way that they represent if the the sub column was observed in that specific row or not:

output1:

```
    c1.20022 c1.31012 c2.44444 c2.22233 c2.87634 c3.44444 c3.00444
    1   1      0        1       0         0         1      0 
    2   0      1        0       1         0         1      0
    3   0      1        0       1         0         0      1
    4   1      0        1       0         0         0      1
    5   1      0        1       0         0         0      1
    6   1      0        1       0         0         0      1
    7   0      1        1       0         0         0      1
    8   0      1        1       0         0         0      1
    9   0      1        0       0         1         1      0
    10  1      0        0       0         1         1      0
```

My real data has moreover than 100000 columns and rows.
I should also mention that I want to run this program in Linux.

secound part: I want to delete those characters which repeated less than a hundred times within each column and I do not want any sub-column for those. for exaple in my example input.file I want to delete those characters which are repeated less than 3 times:

input2:

```
 1 20022 44444 44444
 2 31012  NA   44444
 3 31012  NA   00444
 4 20022 44444 00444
 5 20022 44444 00444
 6 20022 44444 00444
 7 31012 44444 00444 
 8 31012 44444 00444
 9 31012  NA   44444
10 20022  NA   44444

And output:

output2:
     c1.20022 c1.31012 c2.44444 c3.44444 c3.00444
    1   1      0        1         1      0 
    2   0      1        0         1      0
    3   0      1        0         0      1
    4   1      0        1         0      1
    5   1      0        1         0      1
    6   1      0        1         0      1
    7   0      1        1         0      1
    8   0      1        1         0      1
    9   0      1        0         1      0
    10  1      0        0         1      0
```

What I should change in shell script written below in the answer , in order to directly reach from my first input(input1) into the last output(output2) ?

a bit update:
if in my input each 2 line be representation of one individual(line 1 and 2 belongs to individual 1):

```
1 20022 44444 44444
1 31012 44444 44444
2 31012 00000 00444
2 20022 44444 00444
3 20022 44444 00444
3 20022 44444 00444
4 31012 44444 00444 
4 31012 44444 00444
5 31012 11112 44444
5 20022 11112 44444
```

and I want in my output.txt each individual be repeated only one time while converting each character within each column as a sub-column and I want to put either 2 or 1 or zero in rows in the way that they represent how many times each character repeats within a sub-column for each individual. Meanwhile I want to delete those characters which are repeated less than 3 times within each column(here 00000 and 11112 from column2):

output1.txt:

```
  c1.20022 c1.31012 c2.44444 c3.44444 c3.004444
1      1       1         2        2        0
2      1       1         1        0        2
3      1       0         1        0        2
4      0       2         2        0        2
5      1       1         0        2        0
```

here in out put I put spaces between digit numbers in order to make it understandable. but in fact those spaces not be needed(ex: first line: 1 11220)

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're asking. Do the numbers have to be processed as strings? I see in your example that `00444` is not simplified to `00444` - is there a difference between `00444` and `444`?

Comment: @Ross. yes. it must stay 00444. because it is a character and not a value.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728396/how-to-covert-character-within-each-column-as-sub-column-without-duplication

Comment: @ that solution is in R not n fortran. My data is huge and R does not have enough memory for this

Comment: Still related. Maybe a small modification would suffice. The same limits will apply in Fortran as in R. Did you try anything? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: And why fortran? This would be much easier with shell utilities, which would be natural for linux.

Comment: And are the labels (possible data values) known in advance? Or do those have to be determined from the data files?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: if you know how to do it i shell then let me know. I was not aware if I could do that in shell. Please let me know if you can. I did this in R. but R does not hav enough memory for my whole data. So I thought maybe fortran is suitable for my huge data

Comment: Well, I would never use fortran for file/string manipulation. I'll think about it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a non-fortran solution I wrote a (g)awk script which does what you want, and your file should be given to it twice. In the first run it builds an array of the labels appearing in each column, which is the only memory-heavy step in the process. In the post-processing phase each column is processed one-by-one, line after line independently, so I guess its utility depends on the distribution of header values.

**Important note**: the script utilizes real 2d arrays of the syntax [`labels[i][$i]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html) rather than standard `awk`'s [`array[i,j]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html) syntax in order to be able to loop over the second index. This will work in [`gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html), but other `awk` flavours might not support it.

`foo.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk

#set up label array from first run
NR==FNR{
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
    labels[i][$i]=1;
  }
}

#do actual printing in second run
NR!=FNR{
  if(FNR==1){   #then print header
    printf "       ";
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){   #i corresponds to columns in input
      for(label in labels[i]){
        printf " c%d.%s ",i-1,label};  #note i-1
      }
      print ""; #newline
  };

  printf "%10d", FNR; #column 1: line number
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
    for(label in labels[i]){  #loop over every possible label in column i
      if($i==label){
        printf "    1     ";  #1 if same
      }
      else {
        printf "    0     ";  #0 if different
      }
    };
  }
  print ""; #newline
}
```

And a front-end, `bar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=$1

gawk -f foo.awk $infile $infile
```

which you run by `./bar.sh infile` after setting it to executable, where "`infile`" should be replaced by the actual name of your input file. Obviously you can skip the shell script and just call `gawk -f foo8.awk infile infile`, but I for one am too lazy to do this more than once.

Also, note that you probably want to remove most of the whitespace in the `printf` commands. Those are in there for a pretty output, but you probably won't be looking at the output by hand, but rather with some automated post-processing method. But all this whitespace would blow up the already huge file you end up with. So I suggest keeping a single space at the beginning of each `printf` in order to separate your columns from one another, and removing the rest.

Output:

```
c1.20022  c1.31012  c2.44444  c2.87634  c2.22233  c3.00444  c3.44444 
 1    1         0         1         0         0         0         1     
 2    0         1         0         0         1         0         1     
 3    0         1         0         0         1         1         0     
 4    1         0         1         0         0         1         0     
 5    1         0         1         0         0         1         0     
 6    1         0         1         0         0         1         0     
 7    0         1         1         0         0         1         0     
 8    0         1         1         0         0         1         0     
 9    0         1         0         1         0         0         1     
10    1         0         0         1         0         0         1
```

### Update

Regarding your updated question:

> I want to delete those characters which repeated less than a hundred times within each column and I do not want any sub-column for those. for exaple in my example input.file I want to delete those characters which are repeated less than 3 times

It's your lucky day, as the above script only needs trivial changes to make that happen. For this we change the `labels[i][label]` variables from indicator to counter, i.e. we keep incrementing their value when we find the same label. Then during the second run we simply skip those labels which appear at most 2 times.

Updated `foo.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk

#set up label array from first run
NR==FNR{
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
    labels[i][$i]++; #counter instead of indicator
  }
}

#do actual printing in second run
NR!=FNR{
  if(FNR==1){   #then print header
    printf "       ";
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){   #i corresponds to columns in input
      for(label in labels[i]){
        if(labels[i][label]<3) continue;  #skip labels which appear at most 2 times
        printf " c%d.%s ",i-1,label};  #note i-1
      }
      print ""; #newline
  };

  printf "%10d", FNR; #column 1: line number
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
    for(label in labels[i]){  #loop over every possible label in column i
      if(labels[i][label]<3) continue;  #skip labels which appear at most 2 times
      if($i==label){
        printf "    1     ";  #1 if same
      }
      else {
        printf "    0     ";  #0 if different
      }
    };
  }
  print ""; #newline
}
```

Output:

```
c1.20022  c1.31012  c2.44444  c3.00444  c3.44444 
 1    1         0         1         0         1     
 2    0         1         0         0         1     
 3    0         1         0         1         0     
 4    1         0         1         1         0     
 5    1         0         1         1         0     
 6    1         0         1         1         0     
 7    0         1         1         1         0     
 8    0         1         1         1         0     
 9    0         1         0         0         1     
10    1         0         0         0         1
```

### Update 2

Regarding your twice updated question,

> a bit update: if in my input each 2 line be representation of one individual(line 1 and 2 belongs to individual 1):
>   ...

Now you have data spanning two lines each, and you want to treat them together. Note that as your problem becomes more complicated, the solution does as well. In order to spare complications, I assumed that you have **exactly 2 lines** for each individual, which seems to be the case. I also had to assume that the first line in your input file starts with a 1. This also seems to be the case, but the above solutions didn't make use of this. As a matter of fact, it is assumed that the individuals span a range from 1 to the total number of individuals, without gaps. It could be done in a more general way, but I didn't want to overcomplicate it for no reason.

new `bar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=$1

cat $infile $infile |paste - - |gawk -f foo.awk
```

this will put each pair of input lines next to each other such that now each individual is again only on one line, then feed this modified file twice to `foo.awk`.

new `foo.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk

#keep count of number of files (from first colum of first row)
{if($1==1) nfiles++;}

#set up label array from first run
nfiles==1{
  for(i=2; i<=NF/2; i++){ #go over first half columns
    labels[i][$i]++;        #odd lines
    labels[i][$(i+NF/2)]++; #even lines
  }
}

#do actual printing in second run
nfiles==2{
  if($1==1){   #then print header
    printf "       ";
    for(i=2; i<=NF/2; i++){   #i corresponds to columns in input
      for(label in labels[i]){
        if(labels[i][label]<3) continue;  #skip labels which appear at most 2 times
        printf " c%d.%s ",i-1,label};  #note i-1
      }
      print ""; #newline
  };

  printf "%10d ", $1; #column 1: line number
  for(i=2; i<=NF/2; i++){
    for(label in labels[i]){  #loop over every possible label in column i
      if(labels[i][label]<3) continue;  #skip labels which appear at most 2 times

      multi=0 #multiplicity of label "label" in line i
      if($i==label) multi++;
      if($(i+NF/2)==label) multi++;

      printf " %3d    ", multi;

    };
  }
  print ""; #newline
}
```

Input:

```
1 20022 44444 44444
1 31012 44444 44444
2 31012 00000 00444
2 20022 44444 00444
3 20022 44444 00444
3 20022 44444 00444
4 31012 44444 00444
4 31012 44444 00444
5 31012 11112 44444
5 20022 11112 44444
```

Output:

```
c1.20022  c1.31012  c2.44444  c3.00444  c3.44444 
 1   1       1       2       0       2    
 2   1       1       1       2       0    
 3   2       0       2       2       0    
 4   0       2       2       2       0    
 5   1       1       0       0       2
```

Note that you can just remove most of the extraneous whitespace by changing

```
printf " %3d    ", multi;
```

to

```
printf "%d", multi;
```

And also note that my example output is different from yours, but from your specification it seems to me that my version is the correct one (for instance, for individual 3 there should be a "2" in the first column).

Comment: @ Andras Deak: your solution is simply amazing! I am running my huge dta by this solution. It is still running. I hope it go to the end of running without any error.

Comment: @ Andras Deak:I have a question please. my input-file name is haplotype.txt . should I replace my file name by "infile" from your solution?

Comment: @zara, indeed, "infile" should be replaced by the actual name of your input file. Sorry for not pointing this out in the first place. Also: thank you for the accept, but you should make sure that my solution actually works for your problem. And if it doesn't, let me know and we'll figure out a solution:)

Comment: @ Andras Deak: actually I replaced my file name (which is a txt.file) instead of infile in bar.sh content but I got error and an emty output file

Comment: I run this:$ ./bar.sh hap.txt > outout.txt 

and I get this error: $ ./bar.sh: line 1: hap.txt=hap.txt: command not found

Comment: @ Andras Deak: I replaced my file name in bar.sh in this way:

#!/bin/bash

hap.txt = $1

gawk -f foo.awk $hap.txt $hap.txt   please let me know why it does not get run?

Comment: @zara: **don't** replace anything in the shell file. Just run `./bar.sh hap.txt` as it is. Also: if you want to make sure it runs fine (without first waiting for all 100000 lines), then first run `./bar.sh hap.txt |head -10 >tmp.out`, then check `tmp.out` which should contain the first 10 lines of the output. If it gets there fine, it will have no problem going over all 100000 lines (as `awk` works from line to line, no additional memory problems could arise). (And this initial check will run **much** quicker.)

Comment: @ Andras Deak:Alright. I did it and what I see in output file is like what I want except a few thousands of last columns are empty. My mean is that I do not see any 1 or 0 below them. why is that do you think? because at least I should see zero and not nothing. meanwhile I have saved my out put as txt.file and not tmp.out

Comment: @zara OK, the filename is irrelevant. Are you sure there are missing columns? If the width of your column labels does not have length 6 but something else, the spaces will be off. Try running `awk '{print NF;}' txt.file`: this will print out line by line the number of columns in the file. It should write the same number in each line except for line 1, which is one column shorter. What does it print for you?

Comment: Andras Deak:okay. it shows number of columns is 185562 for all rows. which means everything is alright and only reason is that the width of columns causes that it look like what I saw. thank you! :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Then go ahead and run the actual script without the `head -10` part. But I strongly suggest first removing the unnecessary whitespace from the `printf` commands. Otherwise you might end up with a file a few dozens of TB in size.

Comment: @ Andras Deak: definitally I will do that and let you know if I had problem.

Comment: @ Andras Deak: One mor question: when I check the number of column for my out put, for all rows , it shows  185562 columns except for last row which shows 176295 column. why is that?? and when I check number of rows by wc, it says number of rows for input.file is 37 but in output is 38. why is that do you think?

Comment: @zara Well, there could be 2 things for the number of lines. Did you take into account that the output has a header line as extra? And if you did, the trailing newline at the end of the last line may account for an extra line with wc (compare `echo "asdf" |wc` and `echo -e "asdf\n" |wc`). As to why the column numbers are off: they actually shouldn't be.  Check your original input file with the same method (`awk '{print NF;} input.file |tail -10'` to get the output for the last 10 lines): does the last line contain the same number of columns there?

Comment: @ Andras Deak: yes you were right. for column number in my input file , the last row was not complete. thank you. does this program work the same, if I delete those character which have repetition less than 100 time within each column in my input file? I mean I want to set any character within each column with repetition less than 100 times into NA or zero(something to make them distinguish from others. and then I want to run your program. so I do not want any sub column to be made for them. I am also investigating how to do this. but after I figure it out, does your codes work well on them?

Comment: @ Andras Deak:      I added some more information on my question body to make it understandable that what my final input may look like.

Comment: @zara, see my updated answer. But please be considerate with those who take their time and answer you: ask your full question in advance to make your intentions clear. Sometimes new constraints might need a completely new angle to approach the problem (fortunately this is not the case now).

Comment: @zara: just to be clear: with my updated code you **don't have to** (and **shouldn't**) change those values to "NA" or anything else. The script will count the number of occurences by itself. Just change the `<3` conditions to `<100` (but I find `<3` to be much more *lovely*).

Comment: @ Andras Deak Ha ha funny! Andras I thank you so much for your effort and help. could you recommend me any source or site for learning to write program in shell?  the only software I have worked so far is R and a littl bit SAS. But since I work by genomic data, R does not have enough memory for data files I am dealing with. So I need to learn something else :(

Comment: @zara, I can only point you to that vast source of information, The Internet. But getting to grips with `bash` and utilities such as `awk`, `sed`, and `grep` can be immensely useful. [Here's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2436) a set of links from someone else. A taste of possibilities can be found [here](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-data.html).

Comment: @ Andras Deak : Thank you for introducing this to me. It is useful I think :-)

Comment: @ Andras Deak sorry for bothering you again. I do not know why when I use my whole data (about 117000 rows and 10,000 columns), and I run the program it gets stop after long time(about 500 minutes) without ending.

Comment: @ Andras Deak sorry for bothering you again. I do not know why when I use my whole data (about 117000 rows and 10,000 columns), and I run the program it gets stop after long time(about 500 minutes) without ending.  But if I use subtract a small part of my data (for example I tried by only first 200 row) , the program runs to the end and out put had same number of rows as input. but for my whole data, there is a huge gap between number of row in input and output.: wc input.txt
    117355 1060654490 6363574875 input.txt. and wc ouput.txt
19308      652268 12229320704 output.txt.  why is that?

Comment: just as more information this is the way that I run the program :    ./bar.sh input.txt  > output.txt &

Comment: @zara, that should not happen. So something funny is going on. How large is your `output.txt` file eventually? Is there enough space left on the hard drive...? (You can use `du -sch outfile.txt` to tell you the file size, and `df -h` to tell you among other things the available space, if you know how to read the output) Have you removed the whitespace from the awk script, and if not: does removing the whitespace lead to a larger number of lines in the output?

Comment: @ Andras Deak, I again ran the program and it is still runing, my inputfile has 6.1G and my outputfile is 7.4G after of 220 minutes running. and the output size is increasing constantly. so far output has 12000 rows I guess if  the program does not stop , the out row must reach to 117000. meanwhile I removed whitespace from the awk script. so it shuold not be the problem. this time I used this command in order to let the program runs in main server: nohup  ./bar.sh input.txt > output.txt &   So I let you know what will be the final size of output, as soon as program stop running.

Comment: @zara, so, any news?:)

Comment: @ Andras Deak,hello! yes after 30 hours I got a out put file with 71G size :)

Comment: @ Andas Deak, Any way I have another question which is like the previous one but a little different. may I ask you? (in case if you have time let me know and I will update my post.)

Comment: @zara: so do you have every line you need then? And if you have another question, you might want to ask it independently. If it's very closely related, then please consider asking your final question instead of keeping updating it:P But sure, go ahead, I'll take a look (but not today) (and if not me, someone else probably will).

Comment: @ Andras Deak yes I have every line that I need . I will update  my post soon(couple of days.. i just want to be sure about the final output that I need). hopefully you will be here. please do not delete any of your comments since I need them :)

Comment: @zara, couple of days is fine by me, I'll be around. Write me a comment when you're ready. I will not delete my comments, although someone might delete/move them due to their large number: again, in this case send me a comment and I can tell you anything you need.

Comment: Hello! I hope you have some times to look at the my update in this post :)

Comment: I do know why I can not type your name :((

Comment: @zara, because you and I are the only ones in this comment thread, and I as the author of the answer am automatically notified of new comments. You, on the other hand, have to be notified manually -- this is why I always explicitly type out your name:)

Comment: --@Andras Deak , okay now I understand :) I just updated my post. could you please look at that when you have some times ?

Comment: @zara, I almost have a solution to your updated question, however something's not clear. How can you have c4 in your output if your input only has 3 columns? Please specify what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry it was a typo.  i just edited it. I should also mention that my real data is as huge as before.

Comment: Andras Deak , are you sure the updated foo.awk is the one that you got the output? I ran it on this small example and the out put that I see is not the one that should be while the input is exactly the same.

Comment: I do not know how to show you the output here. when I copy and paste it here in comments the structure get ruin but  I try to show you

Comment: 1 02111  2 20220  3 11220  4 02111  5 10

Comment: @zara I now copied the exact codes into new files to test. If you use the new shell file, the new awk file and the input that I wrote there, I get what I wrote as output. Are you sure you copied each file perfectly?

Comment: @zara, I don't really think I can figure out what's wrong. I'll think about it. In the mean time you make sure again to copy the new scripts to a new place to avoid any possible confusion with earlier versions.

Comment: the problem got solved now. i am not sure how much time you spent on this. but you may not know how much this mean to me :) I really appreciate that.

Comment: @zara, I'm really glad I could help:) Usually "this is my problem, what code will solve it?" type of questions are discouraged on SO. But in your case it was obvious that with very little effort I can solve your otherwise complicated problem. So don't worry, it wasn't much work, and I know it's of much more help to you:)

Comment: Hello again. I hope I could ask you a question  after long time. May I ?

Comment: @zara I suggest asking a new question on Stack Overflow, I can't help you at the moment. Feel free to link back to this question, in case the problem is related.

Comment: The problem is directly related to this question. I update the question now

Comment: @zara why are you asking me if you should ask me here if you're ignoring my answer anyway? Don't let your question become a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) (any more than it already is).

Comment: @ sorry I did not want to bother you. My english not good that much. May be I misunderstood you. I though that your are saying if my new question is related to this question then I can ask

Comment: @zara no, I said that you should ask a new question. And *if* it's related, then also link back to this question, if it makes any difference. It's also OK if you don't link back to this question, it was only a suggestion. The main point is that after all this time we should leave this question-and-answer pair as it is.

Comment: ok now I understand. But how can I link back this onld question  to my new questin?

Comment: @zara I just meant something like "*This is related to my original question >>put a link here or something<<, and now my question is...*". Nothing special, only if it makes sense in context. Just try to be informative and helpful, and make it so that your new question doesn't get closed as a duplicate of this one. That's all I can help right now. Good luck.